# add attribute in jQuery using class

Tags: jquery

I was able to add the attribute tab index using the id like this:

```
 $("#idname").attr("tabindex", "0");
```

but when I tried it with class

```
 $(".classname").attr("tabindex", "0");
```

it doesn't work

Comment: "*I want to remove a button thats within a couple of divs*" - and what's not working? What's your question? Kudos for adding your code, although the `.dashboard-container` and `#multi-reports` both appear to be missing from your html, but it's not clear what you need help with.

Comment: That button is only in _one_ div (not a couple). If you intend for it to be in more than one div you'll need to ensure it has a unique id (duplicates are not allowed). Consider using a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. I am highlighting container in grey, click anywhere on that grey area and button will be removed.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".container").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#go-back").remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="background:grey">
  <div class="reports">
    <div class="header">
      <button id="go-back">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>Go Back
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work:

```js
$(function() {//document ready
  $(".dashboard-container").on("click", "#multi-reports", function(e) {
    $("#go-back").remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <button id="multi-reports">
       Click to remove
</button>
</div>


<div class="reports">
  <div class="header">
    <button id="go-back">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Go Back
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A solution with pure JS:** Note the `click` event is on the `multi-reports` button and not the `div`

```js
document.getElementById("multi-reports").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("go-back");
    if(element){
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-container">
   <button id="multi-reports">
   Click to remove
   </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="reports">
   <div class="header">
      <button id="go-back">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Go Back
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```